# Parsing JSON data and showing in a table using loop

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm developing a website with Laravel where I've a JSON response from server like below:

```
[{"id":1,"user_id":"1","patient_name":"kk","age":"44","sex":"Male"},
{"id":2,"user_id":"1","patient_name":"noor","age":"7","sex":"Male"},
{"id":3,"user_id":"1","patient_name":"noor","age":"44","sex":"Male"}]
```

How can I iterate through this JSON object so that I can show the data in a table with patient_name, age, sex column in blade view file?

Comment: I see you are new to Stack overflow, would you also consider upvoting the correct answer(s) so other people can clearly see that it could be a possible solution? This could help other people a lot.

Comment: Well I need 15 reputation points for upvoting but I've only 7. I'll upvote when I'll get the points @SvenHakvoort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will have to convert the JSON to an array in the controller file using the [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method as `$array_data = json_decode($array, true)`, then you can pass the data to your view from the controller as `return view('page', ["array_data" => $array_data]);`.

```
$array_data = json_decode($array, true);

return view('page', ["array_data" => $array_data]);
```

*Note that the `page` must be the name of your view blade template file name minus the `.blade.php`, i.e. if your template is called `page.blade.php` you have to use just `page`.*

Finally, you have to parse the passed data in your view blade template file like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>User id</td>
    <td>Patient name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Sex</td>
</tr>
@foreach($array_data as $key=>$value){
<tr>
    <td>{{$value["id"]}}</td>
    <td>{{$value["user_id"]}}</td>
    <td>{{$value["patient_name"]}}</td>
    <td>{{$value["age"]}}</td>
    <td>{{$value["sex"]}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```